# Winforms custom control in visual studio, redirect it's child controls mouse click to parent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am making a winforms custom control in VS2013, inside I have other controls, mostly panels. I want the click events on the panels to propagate to the custom control.

So when I add the custom control to another project, When I add a click event on that custom control, I want it to fire regardless if I click on the control itself or a panel inside where I redirected the click event. Some other controls in the custom object I do not want to redirect the click event.

Currently the click events only fires if the user clicks in an area of the custom control that DOES NOT have another child object (i.e. panel) in that location.

Thanks.

Details:

```
        // panel on click
    private void panel1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        Point coord = me.Location;
        MessageBox.Show("Panel: " + coord);

        MouseEventArgs mee = new MouseEventArgs(me.Button, me.Clicks, me.Location.X + panel1.Left, me.Location.Y + panel1.Top, me.Delta);
        // call component onclick
        this.OnClick(mee);
    }
```

Then the user implements the click event when adding the component!

[Component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn5tM.png)

Comment: it would be useful if you provide some code and screenshots. your question is not really clear here

Comment: Several ways to do this, but the most straight-forward way is to simply subscribe the panels' Click event and have their event handler call OnClick().

Comment: I would create a static class with static method and use it to the click event of the child's button.

Comment: Thanks Hans, simple is best! I am not that familiar with windows events and such. I added the code above in response to your solution, basically it adjusts the mouse location so the location is correct vs the component. Is this an adequate way to do it?